# ifstream still reading after eof

Tags: c++, loops, fstream, ifstream, eof

I am writing a program that is going to have to import data from a file into various containers. I have it importing everything properly, but it is continuing to read after what is supposed to be the eof. I have a feeling I am not properly telling the loop when to end, but the code is below for everyone to look at.

```
bool InitLoad(vector<string>&num, vector<string>&name, vector<double>&price, vector<char>&tax)
{
    ifstream invFile;
    int intTemp;
    string strTemp;
    double dubTemp;
    char chTemp;
    string fileLoc = "C:/Users/owner/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/CISS 350/Week 1 Grocery Register/Week 1 Grocery Register/Invent.dat";

    //Open Invent.dat file. Location below is the location used on creators computer. Other may need to modify file location
    invFile.open(fileLoc.c_str(), ios::in);

    //If Invent.dat file fails to open display error message and return false
    if(invFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open inventory file" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(invFile)
    {
        //Read first line of the file
        getline(invFile, strTemp, ' ');
        while(invFile)  //while invFile contains data display import the list
        {
            cout << strTemp << " ";
            num.push_back(strTemp);

            getline(invFile, strTemp, ' ');
            cout << strTemp << " ";
            name.push_back(strTemp);

            getline(invFile, strTemp, ' ');
            dubTemp = atof(strTemp.c_str());
            cout << dubTemp << " ";
            price.push_back(dubTemp);

            invFile.get(chTemp);
            cout << chTemp;
            tax.push_back(chTemp);

            getline(invFile, strTemp, ' ');
        }
    }

    invFile.close();

    cout << endl;
    //Verify Proper input...REMOVE WHEN COMPLETE
    cout << "Verifying input data correct..." << endl;
    int vecSize = num.size();
    cout << vecSize << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
    {
        cout << num[i] << " " << name[i] << " " << price[i] << " " << tax[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try to call while(!invFile.eof()) ?

Comment: @fatih_k That would be a serious mistake.  He's on the right path.  He just needs to check after every `getline` to ensure that it has succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

Your check does not check eof flag 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/

use `invFile.eof()` instead

And also eof flag would be setted **after** reading past EOF

PS: OMG!! do not use `atof`, just do `invFile << dubTemp`

Comment: After I looked a little closer the file I was using had a space after the last bit of data so it was not reaching the eof the loop was restarting.

Comment: that is why is suggest you to use `while(invFile << num_str << name_str << price_fl << tax_ch){...}` form

Comment: This is simply wrong.  Until you know that input has failed, `invFile.eof()` will not necessarily give anything useful.  In particular, the fact that `invFile.eof()` returns `false` does _not_ mean that there is still data to be read.

Comment: @kassak You meant `while ( invFile >> ... )`, I assume.  `<<` isn't defined on an input file.

Comment: @JamesKanze what's wrong in my answer? I said, that eof flag would be set after reading past eof, right?

Comment: @kassak You don't explain how to use it.  In practice, you don't test for `eof()` until after failure, and often (e.g. with `getline`) not even then.  And the eof flag can be set before reading past eof: `std::istringstream s("42"); int i; s >> i;`. After this sequence, `s.eof()` will usually return true, despite the fact that the input has succeeded.

Comment: @JamesKanze it's true, but as I understand, eof rises due to internal attemp `operator >> (istream&, int)` to find integer's end. But I understnad your oppinion

Comment: @kassak Yes.  The problem with `eof` is that is represents an _internal_ event.  I can be used after an input has failed, to determine whether the failure was due to end of file, or to some other cause (e.g. format error), but it cannot be used to determine whether an input succeeded or not.  For this, you need `fail()`, but the ubiquitous solution is to simply treat the stream as if it were a boolean (which in all cases ends up testing `fail()`).

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is space separated you can uses formatted input instead of getline() on every string.
Something along the lines of this.

```
 string lineTemp;
 while(getline(invFile, lineTemp))  //while invFile contains data display import the list
    {
        string strTemp1, strTemp1, dubTemp, chTemp;
        istringstream lstr(lineTemp);

        if(lstr >> strTemp1 >> strTemp2 >> dubTemp >> chTemp) {

            num.push_back(strTemp1);
            name.push_back(strTemp2);
            price.push_back(dubTemp);
            tax.push_back(chTemp);


            cout << strTemp1 << " "
                 << strTemp2 << " "
                 << dubTemp << " "
                 << chTemp << endl;
         }

         else {
             // Something is wrong with the line format.
         }


    }
```

This will read the data in a formated way and to the proper type. Plus you don't have to worry about empty lines or extra characters in lines.

Comment: That's the cannonical solution. But it definitely needs error checking after the reads in the loop as well, before using the data).

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am assuming that he has lines in the input file in this exact format. Of course if we wants to he can break it.

Comment: It's still fairly simple to add the checking.  Read all of the variables first (`lstr >> strTemp1 >> strTemp2 >> dubTemp >> chTemp`), then check whether `lstr` is OK before doing anything else.

Comment: hmm that seems a much cleaner way. There is always a better way :). I will fix it then.